# comparable price of flash guns for canon 60 compared to 400-500w strobes

Tags: canon, wireless-triggers, strobist

After a recent portrait photography session I paid for where I thought all the images were of poor quality I decided that I wanted to be the one taking the studio portraits and getting the emotions/expressions to come out of the subject.

I've been recently more lights (either flash or strobes) for a while now, wanting to get a blown out background look of people but full body portraits not just headshot or body.

I'm not sure of

1) should I go fkash guns like yong nuo or should I get strobes which require mains. Reason being is matt granger did a video showing that 4 X flash guns was about 400w strobe. and this is supported by another video where the person used a light meter on both and a single flash gun metered at f11 while the strobe metered at f22.

if anyone can help me on this argument I'd appreciate it.

from what I can see 1 X4-500w strobe is $500 which is almost the same as 4x95 yong nuo flash gun + triggers for each.

as an example I want to be able to achieve this image - one taken of me in a studio at studio olympia.

[image]

It was suggested to me today that 4X4002 strobes could do this in a high key setting with two at front and two at back with umbreallas. the lights would cost 2000.

oh and ive heard you can get 1000 3000 and 5000+ watt seconds strobes, not sure how much power I would need for a photo like below to completely blow away everything. but would love to be able to replicate that image.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/32gqalvsh4vax0z/_MG_6286.JPG

Answer (score 0):

Look for Paul C. Buff.
They have Alien Bees.

Monolight is much brighter than all speedlites/speedlights.
And they cost much less.

If the reviewers set speedlites at ASA/ISO 100, 28mm, 1/1 full power & subject at 12 feet.
Then do the same for 400ws monolight.

Shoot and you will always see the monolight will be much brighter & has better lighting.
Shoot a lot with that on the flash, the flash will overheat, Fresnel lens will melt, batteries will get very hot.  Your light will show poor lighting & exposures. 
Your flash will die very soon.